# Clarification of CDF to PDF and PDF to CDF

Tags: probability

If a probability density function is given, to find the cumulative distribution function you integrate.

If a cumulative distribution function is given, then you differentiate to find the probability density function.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct (assuming there is a probability density function).

Comment: And how do you check if it exists? Besides function is greater then 0 over the interval?

Comment: If the cdf is absolutely continuous, its derivative exists almost everywhere, and it is the (Lebesgue) integral of that derivative.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot!